# Add data to array dynamically

Tags: android, arrays, navigation-drawer

I'm using [this helper class](http://www.michenux.net/android-navigation-drawer-748.html) to create a navigation drawer in my app and I've got it working successfully to add data dynamically from json file:

```
    NavMenuItem createMenu = null;
                NavDrawerItem[] menu = new NavDrawerItem[]{};
                int i = 1;
                for (Post post : PostsActivity.this.posts){
                     createMenu = NavMenuItem.create(i, post.title+i, false, this);
                     menu = new NavDrawerItem[]{createMenu};
                     i++;
                }

NavDrawerActivityConfiguration navDrawerActivityConfiguration = new NavDrawerActivityConfiguration();
            navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setMainLayout(R.layout.activity_drawer);
            navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setDrawerLayoutId(R.id.drawer_layout);
            navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setLeftDrawerId(R.id.nav_drawer);
            navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setNavItems(menu);
            navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow);
            navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setDrawerOpenDesc(R.string.drawer_open);
            navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setDrawerCloseDesc(R.string.drawer_close);
            navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setBaseAdapter(
                    new NavDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_drawer_item, menu ));
```

The problem is that only the last data in the `posts` array is displayed. How do I iterate the array so that it adds all the data to the `NavDrawerItem` array?

This is how data is added to the array in the original example given by the author:

```
NavDrawerItem[] menu = new NavDrawerItem[] {
                NavMenuSection.create( 100, "Demos"),
                NavMenuItem.create(101,"List/Detail (Fragment)", "navdrawer_friends", false, this),
                NavMenuItem.create(102, "Airport (AsyncTask)", "navdrawer_airport", true, this), 
                NavMenuSection.create(200, "General"),
                NavMenuItem.create(202, "Rate this app", "navdrawer_rating", false, this),
                NavMenuItem.create(203, "Eula", "navdrawer_eula", false, this), 
                NavMenuItem.create(204, "Quit", "navdrawer_quit", false, this)};
```

Comment: `menu = new NavDrawerItem[]{createMenu};` What is this line supposed to do? Is this supposed to add `createMenu` to the array `menu`? Please further specify what you're trying to do. Also, tell us some more about this library that you're using.

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to add `createMenu` to the `NavDrawerItem` array. I've given the link to the library in the question: http://www.michenux.net/android-navigation-drawer-748.html

Comment: I've updated the question. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> menu = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
int i = 1;
for (Post post : PostsActivity.this.posts){
     menu.add(NavMenuItem.create(i, post.title+i, false, this));
     i++;
}
NavDrawerItem[] navItems = new NavDrawerItem[menu.size()];
navItems = menu.toArray(navItems);

NavDrawerActivityConfiguration navDrawerActivityConfiguration = new NavDrawerActivityConfiguration();
navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setMainLayout(R.layout.activity_drawer);
navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setDrawerLayoutId(R.id.drawer_layout);
navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setLeftDrawerId(R.id.nav_drawer);
navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setNavItems(navItems);
navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow);
navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setDrawerOpenDesc(R.string.drawer_open);
navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setDrawerCloseDesc(R.string.drawer_close);
navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setBaseAdapter(
        new NavDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_drawer_item, navItems ));
```

Comment: Don't forget that `navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setNavItems(menu)` should be changed to `navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setNavItems(navItems)`

Comment: Missed that variable, Nathan.  Edited the post.  Thanks!